# Perl find closest date in array

Tags: perl

How do I get the closest date that is earlier than the input date or equal to from an array using an input date?

For example, my array would look like this.

```
@dates = ("200811","200905","200912","201005","201202");
```

and my input date is

```
$inputdate = "201003";
```

How do I get the closest date in the array which is "200912".

The format of the date is YEARMM.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sort the dates, select only the ones preceding the input date, take the last such one:

```
print ((grep $_ <= $inputdate, sort @dates)[-1]);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
use List::Util qw( max );
my $date = max grep { $_ <= $inputdate } @dates;
```

Answer (score -2):

The logic here is to go one year back and change month from January to December if the month is January, otherwise go back one month in the same year.

I don't code much in Perl, the code in PHP is:
(I'm putting it here to give you the logic. Coding it should be trivial)

```
$dates = array("200811","200905","200912","201005","201202");
$inputdate = "201003";
$date = $inputdate;
while ($found==0) {
    if (in_array($date, $dates)) {
        $found = 1;
        echo "the date is " . $date;
    }
    if ($date%100==1) { // if it's january, we need to change to december of the previous year
        $date = $date - 100 + 12;
    }
    else  {
        $date = $date - 1; //go one month back in the same year
    }
}
```

Comment: That's an awful approach. You can the whole array of dates numerous times -- 4 in the example, but could easily be many many more than that -- when only once is necessary. You could even loop over the array billions of times if there's no earlier date.

Comment: @ikegami, I didn't know that  YYYYMM is the standard date format. I've gone through other and I got it now. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: huh? No idea what that means, and your approach is awful no matter what the format is.

Comment: I have to agree with ikegami on this.